# How to check in Python from which class methods is derived?

Tags: python, introspection, method-resolution-order

I have two classes:

```
class A(object):
  def a(self):
    pass

class B(A):
  def b(self):
    pass

print dir(A)
print dir(B)
```

How can I check from which class methods is derived in Python?

For example:

```
getMethodClass(A.a) == A
getMethodClass(B.a) == A
getMethodClass(B.b) == B
```

Comment: FYI `getattr(A, 'a')` is just a silly way to write `A.a`, and `type(A)` is a Python expression that evaluates to `type` - you probably want just `A`.

Comment: @delnan Read question again I was improve it as you suggest - I make mistake indeed good hint.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898037/how-to-check-in-python-from-which-class-methods-is-derived/ which asks how to do the same thing from _inside_ the method, rather than from _outside_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Here is how I'd go about it.

*(This works in python2. I haven't tested it in python3, but I won't be surprised if it does not work...)*

You can iterate over all the "nominees" using `reversed(inspect.getmro(cls))`, and returning the first (by fetching the `next` value of the iterator) which satisfy the condition that it has the relevant `attr`, and that `attr` is the same as the method of the relevant `cls`.

Method identity-comparison is done by comparing the `im_func` attribute of the unbound method.

```
import inspect

def getMethodClass(cls, attr):
   return next(
      basecls for basecls in reversed(inspect.getmro(cls))
      if hasattr(basecls, attr)
      and getattr(basecls, attr).im_func is getattr(cls, attr).im_func
   )

getMethodClass(A, 'a')
=> __main__.A
getMethodClass(B, 'a')
=> __main__.A
getMethodClass(B, 'b')
=> __main__.B

# an alternative implementation, suggested by @chameleon
def getAttributeClass(cls, attrName):
  # check first if has attribute
  attr = getattr(cls, attrName)

  mro = inspect.getmro(cls)
  # only one class on list
  if len(mro) == 1:
    return cls

  # many class on list
  for base in reversed(mro[1:]):
    # check if defined in this base
    try:
      baseAttr = getattr(base, attrName)
    except AttributeError:
      continue
    else:
      if baseAttr.im_func is attr.im_func:
        return base
  # define in top class
  return cls
```

The function can also have the signature you suggest:

```
def getMethodClass(unbound_method):
    cls = unbound_method.im_class
    attr = unbound_method.__name__
    # rest of implementation is the same as before...

getMethodClass(B.a)
=> __main__.A
```

Comment: Looks good but I think better is to use `inspect.getmro(cls)` and not use `reverse` whatever it should work. What do you think? You can also skip first on mro() since first is class tested.

Comment: I guess you're right about using `inspect.getmro`. I'm not sure how you'd expect it to work without `reverse`ing -- it would always return `cls`. Also, skipping the first on `mro()` would make the code more complex, with no apparent benefit -- you'd still need to return `cls` in some cases, so why not include it in the list you iterate over?

Comment: Why exclude first since first always pass condition `getattr(cls, attr).im_func == getattr(cls, attr).im_func` you can set result to cls and try to replace it with first hit `result = cls for x in mro(): if x != cls and ...: result = x` - do you understand me?

Comment: It will lead to such construct x = something, search in loop for replace for x if no replace x will be not changed. BTW for me next() is not know since very rare I will train it.

Comment: Yes, your alternative implementation would work just as well.